# gem list is showing two versions of a Ruby gem immediately after updating the gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, versioning, mime-types

I just updated the mime-types gem with `gem update mime-types`. `gem list` displayed `mime-types (1.16)` prior to updating. After the update `gem list` shows `mime-types (1.17.2, 1.16)`. Why are two version displayed?

More info: I have other Rails projects on the same computer. I have not updated the mime-types gem in any other projects. Running `gem list` from another project's directory (where mime-types has not been updated) displays `mime-types (1.16)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have both versions installed. If you want to delete old versions (which will not always will be possible due to dependencies) use `gem cleanup`.

Comment: Interesting. Sounds like `gem list` displays version numbers for gems in all projects on my machine (as opposed to only the project whose directory `gem list` is run from).

Comment: Gems are installed user-wide or system-wide so yes, it shows gems for all projects.

Comment: To install gems per project you need to use `bundle` or `rvm` gemsets.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of RubyGems do you have? `gem -v`

This is interesting: I have the newest version of RubyGems but my system behaves differently:

`gem list` => all the gems, all the versions. *No matter from where I call it.*
`gem list --local` => same as before but user-wide.

`bundle list` => all the gems in a project (one version per gem)

The same goes for `bundle update` and `gem update`.

`bundle update` replaces the old version by the new one (the dependencies are taken care by bundler), but `gem update` keeps both. So if you want to keep only the newest version, run `gem cleanup`.

`bundle outdated` might be useful: it displays the outdated gems in your project (based on rubygems.org)

Answer (score 1):

This can happen because of gem dependencies.

For example if another gem depends on that gem, and the other gem does not have  a version specified for it, and(/or) it gets updated and if its dependency on that gem's version changes... well you get the idea.
Sometimes I do a bundle and I see a ton of new versions getting downloaded.  All due to changed... dependencies.